# where is swagger for playframework 1.x?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, swagger

The module is still listed on the play site, the link is dead, but the project is very active. Is there a way to get that module or get swagger support in play 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-play

Comment: Cool - thanks. Sorry for the dumb-ass question, but how to I build it into a jar? I am assuming it requires building then importing into my play project.

Comment: when I run ant, it complains of "../wordnik-swagger/modules/swagger-play/lib does not exist"

Comment: nevermind... that was really dumb of me. It's a play project.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it moved here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play-1.2

For newer play version (2.x) check here:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play

Comment: Keep in mind the question is *asking* for a link, so the above is a valid answer IMO. (That said, the question is several years old and was probably considered a valid question for S.O. at the time.)